# Why 100GB disks getting created when I create cluster

Tags: kubernetes

When I run `gcloud container clusters create cassandra-cluster` command, I see that three `100GB` disks are getting created when I create the cluster. I suppose these disks are used by `K8s` and `GCP`. For what purposes are these disks used? Isn't 100GB too big? Could/should be changed to optimise cost?

```
    gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-8ae97f65-4sts        Standard persistent disk    100 GB  europe-west4-a  
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-8ae97f65-4sts    
None
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-8ae97f65-hwd3        Standard persistent disk    100 GB  europe-west4-a  
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-8ae97f65-hwd3    
None
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-8ae97f65-s5lw        Standard persistent disk    100 GB  europe-west4-a  
gke-cassandra-cluster-default-pool-8ae97f65-s5lw    
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These machines will be used for Kubernetes nodes, 100 GB is the default value as I remembered. Nodes store container logs, docker images, etc. GCP probably take safe size for default because image sizes are high depending on the variety. You could set disk properties while [creating](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create). Also, you could create and change your node pool with a proper disk.